# To use a tab host and display all contents of a table which is fed programmatically in android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is the tab layout.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs" />
</RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

This is the table layout i am using..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lltable"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlmine"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:shrinkColumns="2"
            android:stretchColumns="2" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

I enter table rows data from database programmatically in android but when no. of rows are more than the screen size i am not able to see the top rows in table because it goes under the tab. What should I do?

**Output:**

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Provide one screen shot plz.

Comment: http://s28.postimg.org/vvvqut5x9/Untitled.jpg